# Why an InitialContext on Remote EJB3 Session Beans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb, jndi

Why do I need to specify various driver info when I call a remote EJB?

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099
```

Shouldn't we only need to specify the url/port and the EJB container should resolve all that other stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Because all the EJB containers not use the same properties. This properties was for Jboss containers.

By example Glassfish use this properties:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming
java.naming.factory.state=com.sucn.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700
```

Comment: Duh, I know that I am trying to understand why it isn't handled in a more generic fashion.  All you should have to do is point it to the host and the container should resolve all the other stuff.